# Undefined is not an object animated.interpolate react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I am looking at how to animate colors in react native and followed this tutorial https://codedaily.io/screencasts/8/Animate-Colors-with-React-Native-Interpolate

All I have done is first run `react-native init` then replace the code in my App.js with this

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Animated } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
  this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
}

componentDidMount() {
 Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
  toValue: 150,
  duration: 1500
}).start();
}

    render() {
    const interpolateColor = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 150],
      outputRange: ['rgb(0,0,0)', 'rga(51,250,170)']
    });

    const animatedStyle = {
      backgroundColor: interpolateColor
    }
    return (
      <Animated.View style={[{ width: 50, height: 50 }, animatedStyle]} />
    );
}
}
```

And then run `react-native run-android`

And now I keep getting `TypeError:undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.animatedValue.interpolate')`

Comment: There are a 'componentDidMount' repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `componentDidMount` lifecycle method only runs after the first `render`. Therefore `this.animatedValue` will be undefined when the component first mounts.

You can declare the animated value as an instance property on the component, so that it will be available from when the component is first created.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)

  //...
}
```

Additionally, you can't define multiple `componentDidMount` methods as you have here.

Comment: The first `componentDidMount` was supposed to be a `componentWillMount` but I guess that also runs after the first `render`?
Anyway thanks for the help, it works great now.